# How can I Convert DataTable to List{Object, List{Object}} by Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have Entity as below.

```
namespace Entity
{
    public class MasterMenu
    {
        public MasterMenuParent MasterMenuParent;
        public List<MasterMenuChildOfParent> MasterMenuChildOfParent;
    }

    public class MasterMenuParent
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MasterMenuChildOfParent
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ParentId { get; set; } //It's a foreign key that link to MasterMenuParent.Id
    }
}
```

I query data from database and convert to Entity.
For getDataMasterMenu1() I'm using two Loop.
For getDataMasterMenu2() I'm using one Loop and linq.
For getDataMasterMenu3() I want to use only linq, but I don't know how to do and is it possible?

```
using Entity;
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<MasterMenu> list1 = getDataMasterMenu2();
        List<MasterMenu> list2 = getDataMasterMenu2();
        List<MasterMenu> list3 = getDataMasterMenu3();
    }

    //Using two Loop
    private List<MasterMenu> getDataMasterMenu1()
    {
        List<MasterMenu> result = new List<MasterMenu>();
        List<MasterMenuChildOfParent> tempMasterMenuChildOfParent = new List<MasterMenuChildOfParent>();
        DataTable dtMasterMenuParent = new DataTable(); //Assume: I already query data from database and then load to datatable that has field: ID, NAME
        DataTable dtMasterMenuChild = new DataTable(); //Assume: I already query data from database and then load to datatable that has field: ID, NAME, PARENT_ID
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dtMasterMenuParent.Rows.Count; i1++)
        {
            //Select Child Of Parent
            DataTable dtMasterMenuChildOfParent = (from DataRow dr in dtMasterMenuChild.Rows where dr["PARENT_ID"].Equals(dtMasterMenuParent.Rows[i1]["ID"]) select dr).CopyToDataTable();
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < dtMasterMenuChildOfParent.Rows.Count; i2++)
            {
                tempMasterMenuChildOfParent.Add(new MasterMenuChildOfParent
                {
                    Id = dtMasterMenuChildOfParent.Rows[i2].Field<string>("ID"),
                    Name = dtMasterMenuChildOfParent.Rows[i2].Field<string>("NAME"),
                    ParentId = dtMasterMenuChildOfParent.Rows[i2].Field<string>("PARENT_ID"),
                });
            }

            result.Add(new MasterMenu
            {
                MasterMenuParent = (new MasterMenuParent
                {
                    Id = dtMasterMenuParent.Rows[i1].Field<string>("ID"),
                    Name = dtMasterMenuParent.Rows[i1].Field<string>("NAME")
                }),
                MasterMenuChildOfParent = tempMasterMenuChildOfParent
            });
        }
        return result;
    }

    //Using one Loop and linq
    private List<MasterMenu> getDataMasterMenu2()
    {
        List<MasterMenu> result = new List<MasterMenu>();
        DataTable dtMasterMenuParent = new DataTable(); //Assume: I already query data from database and then load to datatable that has field: ID, NAME
        DataTable dtMasterMenuChild = new DataTable(); //Assume: I already query data from database and then load to datatable that has field: ID, NAME, PARENT_ID
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dtMasterMenuParent.Rows.Count; i1++)
        {
            //Select Child Of Parent
            DataTable dtMasterMenuChildOfParent = (from DataRow dr in dtMasterMenuChild.Rows where dr["PARENT_ID"].Equals(dtMasterMenuParent.Rows[i1]["ID"]) select dr).CopyToDataTable();
            result.Add(new MasterMenu
            {
                MasterMenuParent = (new MasterMenuParent
                {
                    Id = dtMasterMenuParent.Rows[i1].Field<string>("ID"),
                    Name = dtMasterMenuParent.Rows[i1].Field<string>("NAME")
                }),
                MasterMenuChildOfParent = dtMenuChildOfParent.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
                new MasterMenuChildOfParent
                {
                    Id = row.Field<string>("ID"),
                    Name = row.Field<string>("NAME"),
                    ParentId = row.Field<string>("PARENT_ID")
                }).ToList()
            });
        }
        return result;
    }

    //Using linq
    private List<MasterMenu> getDataMasterMenu3()
    {
        List<MasterMenu> result = new List<MasterMenu>();
        DataTable dtMasterMenuParent = new DataTable(); //Assume: I already query data from database and then load to datatable that has field: ID, NAME
        DataTable dtMasterMenuChild = new DataTable(); //Assume: I already query data from database and then load to datatable that has field: ID, NAME, PARENT_ID

        //How can I Convert DataTable to List{Object, List{Object}} by Linq

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an ORM for this? All of this code could be replace with a singel `dbContext.MasterMenu.Include(m=>m.MasterMenuChildOfParent).ToList()`. By using DataTables you are using double the memory too.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Panagiotis Kanavos. I will study ORM.

Comment: The child table has an extra column. So if you cloned the parent table and added the ParentID column you could do it with one linq.

Comment: Mr.jdweng, I don't understand. Could you show me a code, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is nest your LINQ:

```
private List<MasterMenu> getDataMasterMenu3() {
    var dtMasterMenuParent = new DataTable();
    var dtMasterMenuChild = new DataTable();

    var result = (from p in dtMasterMenuParent.AsEnumerable()
             join c in dtMasterMenuChild.AsEnumerable() on p.Field<string>("ID") equals c.Field<string>("PARENT_ID") into cj
             select new MasterMenu {
                 MasterMenuParent = new MasterMenuParent { Id = p.Field<string>("ID"), Name = p.Field<string>("NAME") },
                 MasterMenuChildOfParent = cj.Select(c => new MasterMenuChildOfParent {
                     Id = c.Field<string>("ID"),
                     Name = c.Field<string>("NAME"),
                     ParentId = c.Field<string>("PARENT_ID")
                 }).ToList()
             }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is my expected. Thank you very much.